# Is the current Israel/Gaza conflict "war" or "law enforcement"?

Tags: international

My understanding is that Israel justifies its actions on the West Bank as enforcing [Israeli Military Orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_Military_Order), which they claim are based on international law.

**Do they claim that these still apply to Gaza?**

If not, is the conflict "war" according to international law?

Comment: Does "war" require an identifiable enemy state?

Comment: That's part of my secondary question. I looked through the Chemical Weapons Convention but could not find a definition. They are dropping tear gas on civilians. "Crowd control agents" are legal for law enforcement but considered chemical weapons in war.

Comment: If tear gas is considered "chemical weapons" at all, it's purely via some technicality. Chemical weapons are by definition toxic.

Comment: @cHao From OPCW: ["Riot control agents"](https://www.opcw.org/about-chemical-weapons/types-of-chemical-agent/riot-control-agents/).

Comment: The Convention clearly distinguishes "riot control agents" from "chemical weapons", though. Either way, the agreement is between "State Parties". Which would suggest that as far as the Convention is concerned, warfare requires at least two states. Anything less than one state attacking another, would be an internal conflict.