# How is Israel's situation vs Hamas in Gaza/Palestine remarkable when it comes to evidence?

Tags: criminal-law, evidence, military, laws-of-war, politics

Related: [Does the Israeli military have a legal right to shoot at anyone within the Gaza Strip that they suspect of being a member of Hamas?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96829/does-the-israeli-military-have-a-legal-right-to-shoot-at-anyone-within-the-gaza)

Around 2:30 of [this video](https://youtu.be/wQ3sWktCWMQ?t=150) (also there's a [short](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LeteB_86v8) but without the word 'remarkable'), Uthman Badar responds to Ben Shapiro's debates in Oxford by saying

> This is the *remarkable* nature of this situation: Israel can break *every single* rule of international law, of the rules of war, of basic morality and just shoehorn Hamas into the picture somewhere, and they don't have to prove anything.

**Question**: How is this 'remarkable', i.e. in which war or conflict or '[special military operation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72072/what-exactly-are-the-stated-political-and-military-objectives-of-the-2022-russ)' (or '[law enforcement](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/is-the-current-israel-gaza-conflict-war-or-law-enforcement)') did anyone have to prove anything?

**Guess**:

Well I did read Israel seeks legal advice for each of its military strikes or something. I guess maybe 'prove' isn't meant literally because Israel doesn't have burden of proof since we're all innocent until proven guilty (for humans as well as countries/states), so maybe what's meant is that it's *remarkably* harder for [South Africa](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101150/is-there-a-manslaughter-version-of-genocide) or whomever to prove their case.

Comment: Please do not place speculative answers as part of your question. If you would like to propose an answer, you can provide an actual answer to your own question. If it is just a guess, no need to include it at all

Comment: @Jen Serious? This is the opposite of what people told me before. 1- No research effort. Closed. 2- People prefer 'answering a question' than 'grading an essay'. Closed.

Comment: Yes, look at other highly received questions on this stackexchange. And also read this: [How to ask a good question?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/how-to-ask-a-good-question) On this stackexchange, as long as the legal question is clear, and it isn't _too_ simple (e.g. answered straightforwardly in a simple search), we do not require people to show what they've tried. Guess answers do not even necessarily demonstrate research effort anyway.